# How to export pentaho repository through command line?

Tags: repository, pentaho

I'm trying to export the pentaho repository. there is command line option available to import the code to pentaho repository but not for export.

any suggestion?

I have tried using "Export repository to XML" and it works but it will export as single XML file. not sure how to access.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question.
https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Export+repository+to+XML+file

Answer to your second question:
In order to access the exported repository you have to re-import it in this way you can able to use it(it mainly useful when you want to share the work in a team)

Comment: Agreed, but here after exporting the repository to some local path, I would like to run it from there and not intended to import it again. could you please suggest , how to do this?

Comment: why you want to run something after exporting?
any specific scenario?

Comment: yes, We are dealing with metadata driven solution. native metadata injection works on repository, non native metadata injection done through java. so while browsing the template files, javascript expects templates from Local path and not from the pentaho repository.